# Find Minimum and Maximum in given array where constraints should minimum value index should be less than its maximum

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, min

Given Array ["1510", "1518", "1520", "1523", "1530", "1483", "1485"]
Expected output :-

```
Smallest - 1510
Largest - 1530
```

Another Array ["310", "314", "320", "319", "323", "313", "330"]
Expected output :-

```
Smallest - 310
Largest - 330
```

My code below gets the minimum value and maximum value it's having issues with solving the first problem listed above since it's returning 1483 as smallest and 1485 as the largest. The difference between max and min should be larger.

Any idea on how to get that?

```
function minMax(array) {
    if(array.length <= 0) return [0, 0];
    let max = Math.max.apply(null, array);
    let min = Math.min.apply(null, array);
    let max_index = array.lastIndexOf(String(max));
    let min_index = array.indexOf(String(min));
    if(min_index >= max_index) {
        array.splice(max_index, 1);
        [min, max] = minMax(array);
    }
    return [min, max];
}
```

Comment: btw, why not numbers in the array?

Comment: What if the array is sorted in desc order like `[3, 2, 1]`  Whats that min and max here ?

Comment: There are two possible answers: [absolute min element, max of what's on the right of it] or [absolute max element, min of what's on the left of it].  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @Akhil, Array shouldn't be sorted. It will only be unsorted array.

Comment: @NinaScholz, you can have it as a array of number. This is just something I am working which has array elements as string (which is a number)

Comment: @georg, I am not looking for absolute min and max to right of it. I am looking for a minimum element in array and maximum element for which difference is high in given array of numbers.

Comment: @KailashPrabhu: what is the expected result for `[4,5,6,1,2,3]`?

Comment: @georg, it should return either 4 as min and 6 as max (As their diff is 2) or 1 as min and 3 as max (as their diff as well 2). But min value index should be less than max value index.

Comment: @KailashPrabhu: that's what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single pass over the array:

1. Iterate from the end of the array to the beginning.
2. Keep track of max and min as well as list of min/max pairs
3. Check each item

   - If the item found is more than the current max,

     - add current min/max to the list of pairs
     - make the current item the max and reset the min
   - Otherwise, if the current item is less than the current min, make it the min.
   - Otherwise do nothing.
4. Afterwards add the last min/max pair to the list.

At this point you have a list of potential min/max pairs to return. You have to check them from the end to the start to find the first one where the minimum is set and return it. Or return a default set of min/max.

```js
function minMax(arr) {
  let max = -Infinity;
  let min = Infinity;
  const candidates = [];
  for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const item = Number(arr[i]);
    if (item > max) {
      candidates.push([min, max]);
      max = item;
      min = Infinity;
    } else if (item < min) {
      min = item;
    }
  }
  candidates.push([min, max]);

  // Instead of return fixed first or last element below code would return first element from last which is finite.
  for(let i = candidates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(Number.isFinite(candidates[i][0])) return candidates[i];
   }
   return [0, 0];
}
console.log(minMax(["1510", "1518", "1520", "1523", "1530", "1483", "1485"]));
console.log(minMax(["310", "314", "320", "319", "323", "313", "330"]));
console.log(minMax(["350", "314", "320", "319", "323", "313", "330"]));
console.log(minMax(["7", "6", "1", "2"]));
console.log(minMax(["4", "3", "2", "1"]));
```

Comment: This works but gives an issue with array like this ["350", "314", "320", "319", "323", "313", "330"]. This array should return 314 as min and 330 as max.

Comment: @KailashPrabhu I see, I didn't realise this was the case. I'll have to think it over, in that case.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly fine and understandable as well. Although Nina's answer works. Marking this as an answer due to less code complexity than Nina's.

Comment: `[7,6,1,2] => [Infinity, 6]`

Comment: @georg, in your array it should return 1 as min and 2 as max. Hope that should clear the confusion out. Oops! spoke too soon. Yes looks like VLAZ code is returning Infinity for above case.

Comment: Reverting back the accepted answer, as @georg pointed out ```[7,6,1,2] => [Infinity, 6]``` above code is returning infinite value.

Comment: I altered the last portion in VLAZ solution, which would return a correct answer. Hope that helps. Instead of returning fixed second last element. I am iterating through from the last to return the first one found without Infinity from the last.

Comment: @KailashPrabhu thanks for the edit. I've added a couple more examples of input and output.

Comment: Thanks, @VLAZ. Marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
function minMax(array) {
    let max = Math.max.apply(null,array)
    let newArray= array.slice(0,array.indexOf(+max)-1)
    let min=Math.min.apply(null, newArray);
    return [min, max];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

- take an array of local min and max values,
- group them to min and max pairs, if both values exists,
- change the max value if one is found on greater indices,
- get the one pair with greatest delta.

```js
function minMax(numbers) {
    return numbers
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            if (!(r.length & 1) === a[i - 1] < v) r[r.length - 1] = v;
            else r.push(v);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            if (i & 1) r.push([a[i - 1], v]);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .reduce((r, [min, max], i, a) => (r || a).map(([left, right], j) => [
            left,
            i > j && max > right ? max : right
        ]), undefined)
        .reduce((a, b) => a[1] - a[0] >= b[1] - b[0] ? a : b);

}

console.log(minMax([1510, 1518, 1520, 1523, 1530, 1483, 1485])); // 1510 1530
console.log(minMax([310, 314, 320, 319, 323, 313, 330]));        //  310  330
console.log(minMax([9, 3, 4, 1]));                               //    3    4
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect! This does returns the expected value I am searching for. But it does looks complicated. Any way to explain it elaborately? It would be easier to understand how it's working.

Comment: @georg, looks like Nina's implementation handles it well. With the case ```[7,6,1,2]``` it returns expected value min as 1 and max as 2.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is same as [buy and sell stock](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/). You first need to buy stock and sell for maximum possible. So at each index you need know the largest element on the right side.

1. Traverse array from the end, and at each index store the max element so far.
   `For the list      [1510, 1518, 1520, 1523, 1530, 1483, 1485] maxList will look like                    [1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1530, 1485, 1485] difference                  [20,   12,   10,   7,    0,    2,      0 ] so answer will be 1510 and 1530.`